# C#, code generation for property "Text" failed. Error Was: Couldn't Find File "...path...image.jpg"

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a couple of `.jpg` images in my Form Project, 
I imported them to be background colors to my form,
but now I excluded them from my project,
I didn't Delete them, they're still in the Resources File.

Although I keep getting this annoying error over and over again..
How Can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you provide the code from which you are trying to get that image resource

Comment: I just chose some of them to be the background for my form via the properties panel, but now I set background to 'none'
I'm not trying to get anything anymore..
I'm getting this error every time I debug or hitting Ctrl+s 
not just one error, it's (N) errors, N: number of pics in the Resources Folder.

Comment: Well, pretty obvious, they need to be part of your project... include them again, or start the resource file from scratch.